# Weird mail problem

Tags: email-server, zimbra

There is a weird problem that I cannot think of any solution. There is a mail server Xs that has couple of domains on it and it is in Datacenter Xd. And there is a mail server Ys that has couple od domains also in another Datacenter Yd.

For only 1 domain and 1 user account the mail dont come. For instance;

tommy(at)domain(in)Xd.com

can send

alice(at)domain(in)Yd.com
but cannot send
hardy(at)domain(in)Yd.com

we tried numerous things and at last we deleted the accounts and created them again, but problem still exists.

What do you think has happened to these accounts ?

Comment: By the way we checked it right now all mail accounts at the specific domain at Yd does not receive any mail messages from domains in Xd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running both sets of servers it might be an idea to start looking at your logs.

Comment: This is what the problem was about, there were already a domain at the datacenter Xd and I was not informed, so the mail message was directly going there. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

To catch all the likely obvious problems:

1. Send some test messages at a specific time so you have something to check the logs for
2. Check the queues on the sending machine in Zimbra's admin console
3. If the messages aren't stuck in a queue (if they are you might have a useful hint as to why) review the logs on the sending server (assuming you have access to them) to see if there is a specific error/warning message regarding them
4. If all seems well on the sending machine, check the junk folders on the receiving accounts
5. Review the mail queues and logs on the receiving server (again, I'm assuming you have access)

Hopefully somewhere in the above you should find a logged report that explains why the mail isn't getting through. Two other things to check: make sure the sending machine can resolve the receiving mail host's address (if this is the issue you should see the mail sat in the outgoing queue for a while with an appropriate error logged, and after said while you should get an error mail back from the sending server saying it has given in) and that the sender isn't on so many blacklists that the receiver just throws the incoming mail out without even dumping it in the junk folders.

Comment: This is what the problem was about, there were already a domain at the datacenter Xd and I was not informed, so the mail message was directly going there. Thank you both.